# Configurar varias versiones de Python en Sublime Text 2 con REPL

Tags: python, sublimetext

Tengo dos versiones de Python y tengo REPL en Sublime Text 2 pero sólo me sale una versión de Python.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para poder elegir entre ambas versiones?

Answer (score 1):

Accedes a `Tools` > `Build System` > `New Build System`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y pones el siguiente código (este sería para poner la versión 3 de Python):

```
{
    "cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Guardas y ya tienes un nuevo build.

El código para poner cualquier versión de Python, es lo mismo pero poniendo la ruta absoluta (tanto en GNU/Linux como en Windows):

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\path\to\desired\version\python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

En GNU la ruta sería algo como `/usr/bin/Python...`